# Combining Three Selects into One

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I've been trying to consolidate these three SQL functions into one.

**Functions**

**Function 1**

```
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_Get_User] (@_CompanyKey INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @UserIDs AS VARCHAR(8000);
SET @UserIDs = '';
    SELECT @UserIDs = @UserIDs + ', ' + x.User_ID
    FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(p.User_ID) as User_ID 
    FROM  [dbo].[Program] AS p WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE p.CompanyKey = @_CompanyKey
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(ps.User_ID) as User_ID 
    FROM  [dbo].[Program] AS p WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Program_Scenario] AS ps WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON p.ProgramKey = ps.ProgramKey
    WHERE p.CompanyKey = @_CompanyKey
        AND ps.User_ID IS NOT NULL) x 
    RETURN Substring(@UserIDs, 3, 8000);
END`
```

**Function 2**

```
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_Get_Source] (@_CompanyKey INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @System_IDs AS VARCHAR(8000);
    SET @System_IDs = '';
    SELECT @System_IDs = @System_IDs + ', ' + Original_Source_System_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT p.Original_Source_System_ID
        FROM [dbo].[Program] AS p WITH (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE p.CompanyKey = @_CompanyKey
    ) a
    RETURN Substring(@System_IDs, 3, 8000);
END`
```

**Function 3**

```
`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_Get_ContractNbr] (@_CompanyKey INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ContractNums AS VARCHAR(8000);
    SET @ContractNums = '';
    SELECT @ContractNums = @ContractNums + ', ' + bi.Contract_Nbr + '-' + 
ISNULL(CAST(bi.Year_Nbr AS varchar(8)),'') + '-' +
ISNULL(CAST(bi.Layer_Nbr AS varchar(8)),'')
    FROM [dbo].[Program] AS p WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Program_Scenario] AS ps WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.ProgramKey = ps.ProgramKey
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Layer] AS l WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.ProgramScenarioKey = l.ProgramScenarioKey
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bound_Information] AS bi WITH (NOLOCK) ON l.LayerKey = bi.LayerKey
        AND ISNULL(bi.Contract_Nbr,'') <> '' --IS NOT NULL
    WHERE p.CompanyKey = @_CompanyKey
    RETURN Substring(@ContractNums, 3, 8000);
END`
```

**My attempted Solution**

```
`SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER((p.User_ID)  +', '+ ps.User_ID) as UserID,
        bi.Contract_Nbr as ContractNumber, 
        p.Original_Source_System_ID as SourceSysID,
        ISNULL(CAST(bi.Year_Nbr AS varchar(8)),'') as UW_Year,
        ISNULL(CAST(bi.Layer_Nbr AS varchar(8)),'') as LayerNumber, 
        p.CompanyKey,
        ps.ProgramKey,
        c.Company_Name  
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Program] AS p WITH (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Program_Scenario] AS ps WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON p.ProgramKey = ps.ProgramKey
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Layer] AS l WITH (NOLOCK) ON ps.ProgramScenarioKey = l.ProgramScenarioKey
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Bound_Information] AS bi WITH (NOLOCK) ON l.LayerKey = bi.LayerKey
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS c with (NOLOCK) ON p.CompanyKey = c.CompanyKey
    AND ISNULL(bi.Contract_Nbr,'') <>'' 
    AND ps.User_ID IS NOT NULL
        WHERE p.CompanyKey between 2 and 100000
        ORDER BY ProgramKey`
```

My data-set is 20k+ rows so I'm unable to share it here, but where I'm struggling is my function is not returning the same amount of rows as the above three functions. Might there be anything anyone sees to possibly solve this issue? (24755 rows vs. 24052 rows respectively)

Comment: How do you wanna consolidate if queries do not use identical tables and different types of joins? Even if you could do it In most cases such universal queries performs much worse. So it's bad idea imho.

Comment: The only join that's different is the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` of the first query.. that can easily be substituted for the first join of my query, yielding the same results. I appreciate your input though.. I'm slowly finding out that this may not be the way to go about things.